# Is this really a multiplicative group? [subgroups of $\Bbb Z/15$]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

When looking at some small multiplicative groups of integers modulo n, such as for 15, I found something that confused me. Due to a miscalculation, I had what looks like another set of integers less than 15 that are closed under multiplication. My question is whether this is really a group and if so, is it the only example or is it just another group in disguise?

Specifically, the actual group elements are {1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14} which are the integers coprime to 15. The set I'm interested in is {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12}, which looks like as Cayley graphs:

[image]

So both images here show the groups arranged as $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ where one group is generated by <2> and <7> and the other by <2> and <3>. Is the one on the right actually a group?

Comment: Pretty unrelated but may I ask how did you do those diagrams?

Comment: I used yEd. In the past, I would have used OmniGraffle, which is very nice. yED is .. fine, but less smooth to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure your second Cayley graph works. $3^2=9\neq1$, so it's not true that <3> acts as a copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ mod 15.

Additionally, since I'm trying to prove a subgroup, simply look for $3^{-1}$ which doesn't exist in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ (as a ring), and therefore cannot be embedded in any subgroup of the multiplicative structure.

Also, $7^2=49=4$, so it's also not true that <7> is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*$, order(7)=4.

Comment: Right, yes I had a feeling there was a simple mistake there. Thanks :) I'll wait a while in case there is anything more to say from anyone (which I doubt) then accept this answer.

Comment: Nonexistence of $3^{-1}$ in the full ring $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ is an easier hole.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I should be much more rigorous in constructing product groups! As for your last point about <7>, you are of course right again - I should have chosen <11> as 11*11 = 121 which is 1 mod 15.

Answer (score 3):

In the second one, $1$ and $6$ are both idempotents, thus it is not a group.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is a multiplicative *monoid*, which means a set with an associative multiplication and an identity element. In other words, it satisfies the usual axioms for groups *except* for the existence of inverses. (As others have already pointed out, only half of the elements in your example have inverses.)